# Multiline regex pattern where start and end is known

Tags: regex

I have a textfile where each line contains a field of a record. Each line has a field identifier starting with V010 ending with V999.

i wanna search (at this moment I'm using Notepad++ using plugin http://www.phdesign.com.au/programming/toolbucket-multi-line-search-plugin-for-notepad/) for all records containing a V056 field.

How do I start setting up a multiline Regex. I'm trying to understand the power of regexes but this time the multiline pattern is a difficulty.

I was thinking something like:

```
^V010.+
```

the dot is any character except new line so adding '\r\n' wil bring me to:

```
^V010.+\r\n
```

Next I want to select an entire record so adding V999$ should do if V999 was the next line, except there are an unknown number of lines in between so adding brackets surrounding de '.+\r\n' should do the trick.

```
^V010(.+\r\n)+V999$
```

except now the first V010 till the last V999 is selected. How do I select 1 Single Record. From there i could look further searching if a single record does contain a V056 field.

file example:

```
A001
A999
V010 V
V020 XXXXXXXXXXX
V021 XXXXXXXXXXX
V040 XXXXX
....
V200 NL
V999
V010 V
V020 XXXXXXXXXXX
....
V999
Z001
Z999
```

Comment: V999 must be groupped and flagged as only one occurence, eg (V999){1}. Also pattern could be marked as multiline search (where . matches the end of line as well). It all depends on the flavor the app is using really, so just read help files and look for "Flags", "groups?(ing)?" in it and such ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should suit your needs:

`V010((.|\n|\r|\r\n)(?!V999))*?V056(.|\n|\r|\r\n)*?V999` ([demo](http://regexr.com?346kl))

- `(.|\n|\r|\r\n)` means *"any char (new line included)"*
- `(?!V999)` means *"not followed by `V999`"*
- `*?` means *"match as short as possible"* (while `*` means *"match as long as possible"*)

Comment: can you explain what is happening in these cases? what does the '\*?' exactly do? The second solution is working for me, but now when I try to add the V056 in between I've sort of the same problem. If one or more records doesn't contain a V056 Field multiple records are selected (my regex: V010(.|\n|\r|\r\n)*?V056(.|\n|\r|\r\n)*?V999)

Comment: @LuukKrijnen You're right sorry, I forgot this rule. I edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but youre answer is not working complete. When checking you're demo i moved the v056 to the second record. As you do you see what i mean.

Comment: @LuukKrijnen Hum, you right, once again. Check my new edit if this finally suit your needs ;)

Comment: Thanks. I learned a lot and it helped me save a lots of manual work.